# Adding dynamic prefix to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm receiving emails in SES where I have a rule to move them to an S3 bucket. I'd like to have dynamically created new prefix every month so I can organize the emails monthly. For the prefix name I'd like: `<s3-bucket-name>/MM-YYYY/` where `MM` being the month and `YYYY` the year.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is unclear. Are you asking now to configure Amazon SES that is using an [S3 Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html) to automatically use a prefix based on the month and year?

Comment: By the way, it is usually better to store under `YYYY-MM` rather than `MM-YYYY` because the files and folders can be sorted alphabetically and will appear in correct time order.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [S3 Action - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html) documentation does not appear to offer an option of having a dynamic (changing) prefix.

You could create an [Amazon S3 Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) whenever a new object is created in that bucket/path, which can [trigger an AWS Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html). You could then write a function that copies the object to a desired prefix and then deletes the original object.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, it would be very helpful to have date functions we can add to the prefix while selecting the s3 bucket option :)

Comment: Feel free to click the `Feedback` button in the console and provide your suggestion.

Comment: Rather than creating an S3 event which triggers a lambda to move/rename the stored email object you could also just create an incoming SES rule which invokes lambda directly, so you can do whatever- store it somewhere specific etc